# Fix the formatting to include leading zeros, when necessary

Tags: datetime, lua

I'm making a countdown timer.  The output isn't showing leading zeros on hours/minutes/seconds less than 10.

I think maybe I need to use string.format somehow, but I'm new to lua and I'm not sure how.

function GetTimeLeft()

```
local dif = os.time(RELEASEDATE) - os.time()
local timeleft = {
    [1] = math.floor(dif/60/60/24), --day
    [2] = math.floor(dif/60/60)%24, --hour
    [3] = math.floor(dif/60)%60,    --minute
    [4] = math.floor(dif)%60        --second
}

local text = {}
for i=1, #timeleft do
    if i == 1 then
        if timeleft[i] > 0 then
            table.insert(text,timeleft[i])
        end
    else
        table.insert(text,timeleft[i])
    end
end

if dif <= 0 then
    text = RELEASETEXT
else
    text = table.concat(text,":")
end

return tostring(text)
```

end

Expected 8:02:08:05
Actual 8:2:8:5

Comment: Replace `math.floor(dif)%60` with `string.sub(100 + math.floor(dif)%60, 2)`

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you very much!

Comment: `os.date("!%j:%T",dif)` almost does what you want.

Comment: Or format: `string.format("%d:%.2d:%.2d", 1, 9, 9)`

Comment: @lhf - It adds one extra day

Comment: @Egor I believe you can add dates together without an issue so you would just need to minus one day. OP here is the reference guide for dates - [Dates Guide](http://www.lua.org/pil/22.1.html)